# Validação com ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validação

Tenho uma aplicação web em .NET Framework 4.6.1 com um método semelhante ao exemplificado abaixo:

```
public class MeuControladorController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]AlgumRequest algumRequest)
    {
       try
       {
          if(!ModelState.IsValid)
          {
             return BadRequest(ModelState);
          }

          // Outras cositas mais...

       }
       catch (Exception exception)
       {
          return InternalServerError(exception);
       }
    }
}
```

A classe `AlgumRequest` está semelhante a isso:

```
public class AlgumRequest
{
   public IQueDor QueDor { get; set; }
   public byte[] Prop2 { get; set; }
   // ...
}
```

A propriedade `QueDor` é uma interface:

```
public interface IQueDor
{
   string Gritar();
}
```

Eis uma classe que a implementa:

```
public class ChuteCanela : IQueDor, IValidatableObject
{
   [Required]
   public string Texto { get; set; }

   public string Gritar()
   {
      return Texto.ToUpper();
   }

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
      if(Texto == "Palavrão")
      {
         yield return new ValidationResult("Calma, acredite que a ideia era acertar a bola. Mantenha a amizade.");
      }
      // ...
   }
}
```

O problema é que ao enviar os dados para o método `Post` a propriedade `ModelState.IsValid` está como verdadeiro mesmo quando eu envio uma instância de alguma classe que implemente a interface e deveria ser invalidado.

É possível resolver esse problema sem deixar de usar a abordagem do `ModelState`?

Comment: Acontece que a propriedade vai ter os membros especificados na interface e, consequentemente, não vai conter as validações que você criou na classe específica.

Comment: E haveria alguma forma de fazer com que a interface fosse também um `IValidatableObject`? A única forma que consigo pensar para solucionar isso seria criar uma classe abstrata e usá-la no lugar da interface. Essa classe abstrata poderia "implementar (de maneira abstrata)" `IValidatableObject`, assim, todos que herdarem minha classe abstrata terão que sobrescrever o método de validação.